# Does one have to ask permission to take something that isn't theirs if they know the owner won't mind?

Tags: halacha, gezel-stealing

For example, if someone were to occasionally print out personal (not for work) things using the office's paper and ink and they know their boss wouldn't mind do they still have to ask their boss permission?